# Commiting drawing from touch events rather than large array

Tags: ios, ipad, drawing

A small portion of my app contains a view were people can take brief notes by drawing on the screen. Currently, I do this by saving the touch points into an array then connecting the dots in drawRect. I know that this isn't the best way to do this but this is only a small portion of my app.

The problem is that after awhile the array of touch points get's pretty large and performance bogs down.

Can someone suggest a better way to do this rather than a giant connect-the-dot's game? I am thinking that at each touchesEnded event I should somehow commit what was drawn during that touch to a separate drawing, then clear out the array but I'm not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a `CGMutablePath` (or `UIBezierPath`) property and append to it. Constructing large paths is very expensive, so you should definitely not do that inside of `drawRect:`. If you do have to construct paths very often, it is generally cheaper to have a few smaller paths than one massive path.

You can also just draw each new path into a persistent `CGLayer` and draw it in `drawRect:`. This is less flexible, but has a fixed memory and processing requirement. You can achieve similar things by updating the `contents` of a `CALayer`.